# Bent over barbell row lower back pain

Tags: lower-back, barbell-rows, stiffness

Felt stiffness in my lower back during a week or so(during bent over barbell rows and squats mainly), but didn't pay much attention to it. Yesterday however I couldn't finish my 4x12 bent over barbell row, because of it. So, I skipped it and did the following exercises fine (lat pull-down, seated row, seated cable row etc). A guy in the gym told me that it is typical and that I should wear belt during bent over barbell rows. Is he right? Should I do some special exercises to strengthen lower back (hyperextension f. e.)? Is it okay to do squats tomorrow? (with stiff lower back)

Comment: 12 sets? I think that's excessive. Also, the guy is wrong; ***wearing a belt isn't a panacea for pain caused by bad form.*** Wearing belt is usually recommended when going for personal best ***AFTER*** your form is already accurate.

Comment: 4 sets of 12 reps

Comment: Shouldn't that be ***4x12*** ?

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD fixed it

Comment: I would suggest ***stretching exercises*** tomorrow; you can also perform ***low volume front squats IF*** you need to perform leg exercises tomorrow. I would suggest putting loads on a stiff back.......you've got only one and you certainly don't wanna mess it up.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD is it a good idea to replace planned squat sets with more leg press sets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29026/discussion-between-herokiller-and-kneel-before-zod).

Answer (score 1):

In case barbell rows are one of your main lifts for overall body strength reinforcing your weak links is always a good choice.

When the barbell rows are seen as mere accessory lifts they are quite useless for various reason:

1. Simple dumbbell rows allow for more shoulder freedom and more weight, above of that cheating on dumbbell rows is perfectly safe while cheating on barbell rows will break your spine. Tho good form is recomended anyway.
2. Bench pulls overload the the back better
3. There are better lower back exercises

[Just another reason why simple dumbbell rows are superior](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/10197/dumbbell-bent-over-row-possible-without-bench?rq=1)